# How to get users Longitude and Latitude in PHP?

Tags: php

I would like my page to be able to be personalized for the user viewing and need some help in finding their longitude and latitude instead of it being set to Cheshire UK.

```
<?php
    $info = date_sun_info(mktime(0,0,0), 53.3761, -2.1897); // Cheshire UK

    $rise = new datetime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $info['sunrise']));
    $set = new datetime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $info['sunset']));

    list($daylightHrs, $daylightMins) = explode(':', $set->diff($rise)->format('%h:%i'));
    list($elapsedHrs, $elapsedMins) = explode(':', $rise->diff(new DateTime())->format('%h:%i'));

    $daylight = $daylightHrs*60 + $daylightMins;
    $elapsed = $elapsedHrs*60 + $elapsedMins;
    $percent = $elapsed*100/$daylight;

    printf('Rises: %s<br>Sets: %s<br>Day length: %d minutes<br>Day elapsed: %d minutes (%d%%)',
    $rise->format('H:i'),
    $set->format('H:i'),
    $daylight,
    $elapsed,
    $percent
    );
?>
```

Can anyone please help? I would like the page to be able to tell the users sunrise and sunset wherever they are in the world.

Comment: http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a GeoIP database to look up the latitude and longitude based on thier ip address. Keep in mind that this may not be very precise. While it will probably get a country right, it might be off on the city.

Comment: There are loads of spam websites which seem to know where you are, would you say what you have suggested would be the best method without needing to ask the user?

Comment: Yes, this is generally the way its done. IP addresses are accurate most of the time, but you might notice that a database has a city nearby instead of actual city of the user.

Comment: Could you please help a little more, possibly provide a good link on how I can achieve this using PHP? 

Also, to be able to use this for the entire world, as a fall back, what information should I ask the user, at first I thought about Postal Code/Zip Code but not all countries have these so what exactly would be recommended to ask which is a quick and easy question to pinpoint them to personalize the page for them?

Comment: You should be able to use it for the entire world, accuracy will vary by country. For fallback you probably want to get the city/country, for that however, you need a large database of worldwide cities. Maxmind has a free geoip database here: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite. Its quite easy to use if you install the extension. Provide IP, get back city information + lat, long.

Comment: The only thing I understand how to do, is to download the file(s) on the website provided. I am clueless on what to do next and could use some more help please.

Comment: Using the geoip extentension is probably the best way to make use of it. More information in the [manual](http://php.net/geoip).